# If a user pinged me in a post that later gets deleted, is there any way to see the comment?

Tags: support, global-inbox, deleted-comments

If a user pinged me in the answers/comments of a question (which is not mine) that later gets deleted, is there any way to see what the comment was ?

If i had posted something-technical/code/idea, to which a user responded/corrected/suggested an alternative or even plain criticized me, i would like to hear that, irrespective of whether the post itself gets deleted or not.

Comment: If you don't have 10K and are still unable to view deleted posts then there is no way for you to get at this content.... However, if you post a link to the question, someone else with 10K might be able to help you..

Comment: If you were quick enough to click the inbox before the question was deleted I *think* the inbox item stay there for good. Not sure so posting as comment until proven right or wrong. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Inbox won't show the complete comment, if its long.

Comment: @Liz I did think of that, but that isn't really a solution.

Comment: @AshRj what Lix said is just a way around, hence it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd A very simple solution would be to just provide the complete comment in the Global Inbox. But its safe to assume that somebody would have already proposed that, and it would have been shot down ?

Comment: Just searched and nobody has yet suggested it but I don't think it will be accepted, there's not enough room to show the whole comment it will just be bad design.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The Inbox can be widened

Comment: @AshRj you mean the full inbox on Stack Exchange site? Even there, having full post contents will break the design. Preview which is link to the post is ideal design in my opinion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I mean the Pop Up SE Inbox. Isnt it the one which is called the global inbox ?

Comment: Yes there is the pop up but it also got link in the very bottom of its inbox tab "more inbox messages…" which points to the full inbox on your Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Didnt see that before. So, the SE one is the global inbox. Is there any special name for the pop-up ?

Comment: Sure, you can see it [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/global-inbox/info): Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Is there any point in making this a feature-request ? Or should i just drop it ..

Comment: If you ask me I suggest to just drop it.. chances it will be welcome are pretty small.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you for your responses. I will leave this as it is then.

Comment: @AshRj Never give up, never surrender.

Comment: @iight I cant take them all on my own.